# libvirtd service fails to start after upgrade

Tags: centos7, kvm, rhel7, libvirt

After upgrading Centos,RHEL,Scientific Linux 7.3 to 7.5, KVMs fail to start due to the upgrade:

1.yum install -y,....updates and upgrades your Linux System With no questions asked

"-y accepts everything and installs the packages"

Then when you run:

2.systemctl status -l libvirtd,

....shows that libvirtd service is not active, due to this,

libvirt_storage_backend_rbd.so undefined symbol: rbd_diff_iterate2 - "Error"

Answer (score 1):

RedHat(access.redhat.com) posted a solution for this on 14th Dec 2018

Had a tough time figuring this out, solution:

1.yum update librbd1

2.yum update -y

3.systemctl reboot

login as root

4.systemctl restart libvirtd

5.systemctl status libvirtd

6.virt-manager &

Happy KVMs,

Back to Normalcy

Note: Dependencies Resolved with 
yum update librbd1

Packages are:

1.librbd1 x86_64 1:10.2.5-4.el7 2.4 M

2.boost-random x86_64 1.53.0.27.el7 39 k

3.librados2 1.10:2.5-4.el7 1.8 M

Total download size: 4.3 M

Comment: To add-on to the solution : if somewhat you are unable to see the exact error : "libvirt_storage_backend_rbd.so undefined symbol: rbd_diff_iterate2"...using systemctl status -l libvirtd.... Use libvirtd -v | less... You'll certainly see the error and solve it as described...

Comment: Am seeing -ve votes up in here... Whatsapp? Those having that specific problem are the ones am helping out here.

Comment: This post isn't even on topic here.